# Multithreaded logs not printed to screen

Tags: multithreading, scala, intellij-idea

Code:

```
package org.learningconcurrency.ch3

/**
  * Created by kaiyin on 1/17/16.
  */
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool
import org.learningconcurrency.log

object Ch3 {
  val executor = new ForkJoinPool()
  val executor1 = ExecutionContext.global

  def execute(body: => Unit) = ExecutionContext.global.execute(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = body
  })

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        log("Task run.")
      }
    })
    executor1.execute(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = log("Running")
    })
    execute {
      log("hello")
    }
//    log("hello")
  }
}
```

If I run this in intellij (ctrl+shift+R on a mac), it prints nothing. But once I uncomment the last line in the main function, everything suddenly works:

```
main: hello
ForkJoinPool-2-worker-13: hello
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13: Task run.
ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15: Running
```

Why?

Github repo here: https://github.com/kindlychung/learnConcurrentScala

Scala: 2.11.7
Intellij 15.0.2
sbt: 0.13.8

Comment: Probably the main thread finishes as it has nothing to do besides adding tasks to pool. Try to run your code from repo, Ch3, it usually prints "Task run", but if you tell it to sleep before logging, it won't say anything, program will quit brefore it would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread is finished before other threads could finish. You have two solutions to overcome this problem:

1. Join child threads to main thread using join method on child threads

In the case of an executor, call 'shutdown' method and then 'awaitTermination' method to wait for the threads to complete and then shutdown the executor.

2. Wait for child threads in the main method by sleeping for some amount of time after firing all threads

Comment: How do you join child threads in this case? They are in a thread pool.

Comment: Cool. How about the global execution context? It does not have a shutdown method.

Comment: Unfortunately, the type ExecutionContext is not a 'ExecutorService' which has the 'shutdown' and necessary methods. So, I am afraid it's not possible. I would suggest you go with Await for ExecutionContext based threads